# If energy is conserved then, why should we worry about energy crisis?

Tags: physics

According to law of conservation of energy,"Energy can nither be created nor be destroyed but can be transferred from one form to other". If this is so, then why should we worry about energy crisis?

Comment: The first law of thermodynamics. Once energy becomes heat then it is hard to get work done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Energy cannot be destroyed. That is a fact. But energy can be transformed from one type to another. Thus energy is 'lost' once it is converted into heat energy and this is known as energy degradation by friction and other stuff because heat energy is mostly 'useless'. That is why we should worry about energy crisis.